# Dojo Toggle ComboButton

Tags: html, css, dojo

I have to change functionality of toggle button in web application built on JS Dojo api.
Currently it is dijit.form.ToggleButton, but it should have adittional option for dropdown menu with checkboxes. dijit.form.ComboButton looks like a viable option for that, but the problem is that it behaves like a regular button, and not like toggle button. What would be the best option to solve this problem?

One option I thought of was to manually change style of combobutton to make it look like it is checked, but I'm not really sure how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using a dijit/TooltipDialog with the ToggleButton onChange event?